# How do I know if there is a hole underneath a bad patch job in my ceiling?

Tags: drywall, ceiling, roofing, patching-drywall

How do I know if there is a hole underneath a bad patch job in my ceiling? I am just curious because I don't want a any leaks happening.

Comment: Hopefully if they did a patch job, they had the good sense to fix leak, if that was reason for repair.  Best way to find out is to ask the owner.

Comment: Won’t the hole be above the patch?

Comment: @crip659 Yeah, they said it was from an old roof leak. They replaced the roof (this I know is true because I literally lived next door).

Comment: @SolarMike Yeah it would. Depending on what direction you're looking at it from.

Comment: What type is the ceiling (concrete, drywall/ceiling panels)? How the patch was done - from the bottom or top of the ceiling? Size and thickness of the patch and patching meterial? You need to provide more information with a photo.

Comment: @Ahawkua  If they did a good roof replacement, then you have little to worry about.  A good roof should last 15 to 25 years or more.

Comment: @r13 It's drywall. I have a picture. https://imgur.com/Qzb4sVc

Comment: @crip659 Really? Wow. I thought it was every few years. But doesn't the ceiling protect the inside from rain, or is it actually the roof?

Comment: The ceiling in most cases is just to look nice.  It is only the roof(and outside walls) that protects against weather(rain) from getting in.  If they did a good proper roof replacement, not just a patch here and there, then it should last a long time.